# Program builted fine but it write blank screen

Tags: c

I have problem, sorry if its stupid but Im new to this. I write one program and when I enter variablers its nothing appearing on sreen it say that program is finished but he didnt drive rectangle what is it supposed to do. Any body see what is wrong.

EDIT: I just moved ";" from for loop but just firts if is workin other two are not.

Rectangle should be written similar to this

```
+-------+
|       |  
|       |
+-------+
```

Here is code

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
    int a,b,i,j;
    printf("Enter sites of rectangle ");
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

    for (i=1; i<=a;i++)
    {
        for (j=1; j<=b; j++)
        {
            if (i==1 && (j==1 || j == b)) printf("+"); 
            if (i == 1 && (j > 1 && j < b)) printf("-");
        }

        {
            if (i != 1 && i != a && (j==1 || j==b)) printf ("|"); 
            if (i !=1 && i!=a && (j > 1 && j < b) ) printf (" ");
        }
        {
             if (i==a && (j==1 || j == b)) printf("+"); 
             if (i ==a  && (j > 1 && j < b)) printf("-");

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you entering?

Comment: on first glance, at least '\n' linebreaks are missing

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd cluster of if statements are oustide the inner for loop.

Comment: There's a function called `putchar()` to output single characters; it is smaller and faster than using `printf()` for the job.

Comment: `sides` is misspelled.

Comment: You are making the problem way too hard. Step back and think about it.  Draw your top line, draw your middle lines, draw your bottom line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your latest code paste, this

```
for (j=1; j<=b; j++);
                    ^ this semi colon needs to go away
```

Reason being that, `for (j=1; j<=b; j++);` is the same as `for (j=1; j<=b; j++)` { }

And the code that follows is not in the loop.

Also, here's a hint to draw the top line:

```
putchar('+');
for (j=1; j<=b; j++) {
    putchar('-');
}
putchar('+');
putchar('\n');
```

Same idea for the middle lines ( in a loop ) and then the last line is the same as the first. If you feel that code writes too many '-' you can change `'b'` in the for loop to `'b-2'`

Comment: Thanks, but stil in firts is not workin i dont no whay but he just write to me first if, not other two?

Comment: I'd suggest you forget your previous attempt, take my little code snippet and add on to that. You have the top line now. The rest should follow.